# What's the difference between these two signs

Tags: calculus

[image]

[image]

Are these just two different notations or does each refer to something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is the partial derivative of of a multi-variables function $f(x,y,\ldots)$ with respect to the variable $x$ , such that $f(x,y)=x^2y+\sin(xy)$. The second is the (usual) derivative of one-variable function, such that $f(x)=x^2+2x$. When computing partial derivative with respect to $x$, you compute the usual derivative of the function as a function of $x$, while assuming that $y$ is a constant: 
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=2xy+\cos(xy)y
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{df}{dx}$ is the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$. This is used if $f$ is only a function of $x$.

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$. This is used if $f$ is a function of more than one variable. For instance, if $f(x,y)=x^2y+2y+3x$, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2xy+3$.

Answer (score 0):

Tha 1st one concerns a partial derivative of a multivariate function, while the 2nd one is used for functions of one variable.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to learn from illustrative examples. An explanation may be too lengthy and verbose.

In the first there is one dependent variable $f(x)$ and one independent variable $x$. To indicate this $d$ is used as symbol for them both in the front as the simplest differential operator. While differentiating coefficients are left as they are and unattached constants vanish.

In the second case there are two or more dependent variables $f(x,y,z,..) $ for example $ 8x-2 y+ z^2$ and one independent variable, say $x$. To indicate this operation $d$ becomes $ \partial $ for all the variables, dependent or  independent. While differentiating, independent variable or its functions are operated same way as above, however non-$x$ functions, i.e., other $(y,z)$ or their functions are treated as constant (in  coefficient or additive association) to leave they as they are.